# Quick php question about ordering row results

Tags: php, this

Consider the following :

```
$img_pathm = JURI::root().'images/properties/images/'.$this->datos->id.'/';
$peque_path = JURI::root().'images/properties/images/thumbs/'.$this->datos->id.'/';

$result = count($this->Images);
$resultf = $result-1;

while ($resultf>=0){ ?>

<span class="editlinktip hasTip" title="<?php echo $this->datos->image1;?>::

<img border=&quot;1&quot; src=&quot;<?php echo $peque_path.$this->Images[$resultf]->name; ?>&quot; name=&quot;imagelib&quot; alt=&quot;<?php echo JText::_( 'No preview available'.$img_pathm ); ?>&quot; width=&quot;206&quot; height=&quot;100&quot; />">

<img src="<?php echo $peque_path.$this->Images[$resultf]->name; ?>" alt="Additional image <?php echo $resultf+1 ?>" width="65px" height="50px"/></span>  <?php

$resultf--; }
```

This currently prints images one after the other. All I need to do is to invert the order in which these images are printed to the user. I am not sure where, or how I would insert something similar to ORDER by in this code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop the other way:

```
$img_pathm = JURI::root().'images/properties/images/'.$this->datos->id.'/';
$peque_path = JURI::root().'images/properties/images/thumbs/'.$this->datos->id.'/';

$result = count($this->Images);
$resultf = 0;

while ($resultf<$result){ ?>

<span class="editlinktip hasTip" title="<?php echo $this->datos->image1;?>::

<img border=&quot;1&quot; src=&quot;<?php echo $peque_path.$this->Images[$resultf]->name; ?>&quot; name=&quot;imagelib&quot; alt=&quot;<?php echo JText::_( 'No preview available'.$img_pathm ); ?>&quot; width=&quot;206&quot; height=&quot;100&quot; />">

<img src="<?php echo $peque_path.$this->Images[$resultf]->name; ?>" alt="Additional image <?php echo $resultf+1 ?>" width="65px" height="50px"/></span>  <?php

$resultf++; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Jocelyn I would agree, but this is a link to official PHP manual. But good thing you're doing reviewing.